# Does anyone support RISC or SecEvents specs?

Tags: user-accounts, secevents

I've been reading about the SecEvents WG in IETF (https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/secevent/about/) and RISC at the OpenID Foundation (https://openid.net/wg/risc/). These look like interesting ways to prevent hijacking and abuse across Internet accounts.

Are there any providers that currently support either of these standards?

Answer (score 2):

Google recently announced support for developers whose applications use 'Google Sign In'[1]. You can find instructions on how to integrate in these developer docs[2].

You can see how users of applications can see which apps have integrated with RISC in this blog under 'Cross Account Protection'[3].

[1] https://developers.googleblog.com/2019/02/working-together-to-improve-user.html

[2] https://developers.google.com/identity/risc

[3] https://blog.google/technology/safety-security/google-password-checkup-cross-account-protection/